# Should I write "Appyling any issues" or "Applying any fixes"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this the correct sentence?

> *We support our current releases, unfortunately you are on older version, we are not applying any respective issues.*

Or it should be "*applying any respective fixes.*"?

How should I write it ?

Comment: I think you mean _retrospective_. You apply a remedy to a problem.

Comment: “Applying any issues” sounds like Indian English and is incorrect in American and British English, where software producers would say “We are not releasing further updates.”

Comment: that a user is having a problem with some application.  Frankly, I would grinding my teeth in frustration if I were the user with the problem and received the response above.  How about this more constructive response?  "Sorry you have this problem.  The version you are using is unfortunately no longer supported. So we cannot apply any fixes for your problem.  You need to upload the latest version, which you can do by clicking on this link. The question is not really one of language usage, however, and so my answer is not either.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. I got the answer. To be honest, this sentence is written by an Irish and i had doubt about its meaning but was not able to correct it.